# Get all branches before cloning a repo

Tags: jgit

I'm writing an utility in swing that show all my projects and should let me clone a specific repo and also select the branch I want to switch to, once the cloning process is finished.

The only problem is that in order to show the branches as far as I can see you need to clone the repo first.

Is there a workaround for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list tags/heads on remote repositories via the following snippet:

```
    Collection<Ref> refs = Git.lsRemoteRepository()
            .setHeads(true)
            .setTags(true)
            .setRemote(REMOTE_URL)
            .call();
```

See also this ready-to-run [snippet](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ListRemoteRepository.java) in the [jgit-cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/)

Comment: But with that I cannot see the branches, right?

Comment: Try  setHeads(true)